# AsEnumerable() extension method doesn't work on DataView

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

Why doesn't `AsEnumerable()` extension method work on DataView?

When you initialize a DataView with a certain DataTable, why can't you query it to store the result in a generic collection?

I want to do something like this:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);

List<String> li = (from row in dv.AsEnumerable select row).ToList();
```

Comment: Please show us the code you tried.

Comment: DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
List<String> li = (from row in dv.AsEnumerable
                    select row).ToList();

Comment: As you noted yourself, in order to call a method you need parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method can be used on any type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, it merely implements `IEnumerable`. Since you know that all the items will be `DataRowView` objects, you can use [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like so:

```
List<DataRowView> li = (from row in dv.Cast<DataRowView>() select row).ToList();
```

Note that since you have `select row`, the list element type is `DataRowView`, not `string`.

You could also write it by specifying the type of `row` explicitly, like so:

```
List<DataRowView> li = (from DataRowView row in dv select row).ToList();
```